# Synchronize Google drive with remote web server

Tags: google-drive-api, remote-server

as per the subject I would need to synchronize the contents of some Google drive folders with the same ones located in a shared remote server(web site) .  Normally on the server itself, for internal things, I use a cron.  But in this case I don't know what the correct solution is.  I took a look online but, despite having an idea, I am not sure whether to build specific bees or if there is a more functional way.  Thanks to those who have the patience to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) [Web app deployment](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web?hl=en), and using it as a REST API?

These are the steps to follow:

1. Create a [new](https://scripts.new) Google Apps Script project.
2. Create a Web App that serves the content as a JSON. In my example I will list the folders of Google Drive, but you can use it as you wish. In this example I am implementing a simple API key system for preventing unwanted access.

###### `Code.gs`

```js
const getDriveFolders = () => {
  const listFolders = []
  const folderIterator = DriveApp.getFolders()
  while (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
    listFolders.push(folderIterator.next().getName())
  }
  return listFolders
}

const errMsgRes = ContentService
  .createTextOutput()
  .append(JSON.stringify({ "msg": "INVALID API KEY" }))
  .setMimeType(MimeType.JSON)


const succMsgRes = ContentService
  .createTextOutput()
  .setContent(JSON.stringify(getDriveFolders(), null, 2))
  .setMimeType(MimeType.JSON)

const doGet = (e) => {
  return e.parameter.api_key != "123123"
    ? errMsgRes
    : succMsgRes
}
```

3. Click `Deploy` > `Select type` > `Wep app`. In the `Who has acces` field I put it `Anyone`. Grab the URL for later.
4. In your web site, you only need to fetch the data.

###### `index.html`

```html
<div id="drive-content" ></div>
<script>
const GASURL = "<DEPLOYMENT_URL>";

const container = document.getElementById("drive-content");

fetch(GASURL + "?api_key=123123")
  .then((d) => d.json())
  .then((d) => {
    console.log(d);
    container.innerHTML += d.join("<br />");
  });
</script>
```

This way, every time you enter your web site, the content will be updated.

###### Documentation

- [ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content)
- [DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)
- [`doGet` Request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)